# axios can't fetch data to frontend React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i use axios fetch data from backend to frontend but axios not working

I tried console.log and it still shows the database but not the user interface. don't know where it went wrong. I tried to kill it a few ways but it doesn't show the results I want

instant axios

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/',
  responseType: 'json',
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default instance;
```

fetch data base from backend
ProductScreen

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import MenuProduct from '../components/Product/MenuProduct';
import MainHeader from '../components/Header/MainHeader';
import {POPULAR, Top_Sell} from '../data';
import ProductItem from '../components/Product/ProductItem';
import instance from '../routes/instance';

const ProductScreen = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await instance('/api/products', {
        method: 'GET',
      });
      setProduct(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <MainHeader />
      <MenuProduct list={Top_Sell} />
      <ProductItem list={product} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

ProductCard

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, ScrollView, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {colors, sizes, spacing} from '../../constants/theme';
import AddItem from '../../utils/AddItem';

const CardHeight = 220;
const ProductCard = ({props}) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      return (
      <View
        style={{
          marginLeft: spacing.l,
          marginBottom: spacing.l,
          marginRight: spacing.l,
        }}>
        <View>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: colors.white,
              borderRadius: sizes.radius,
              shadowColor: colors.black,
              shadowRadius: 4,
              shadowOpacity: 0.1,
              shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
            }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                borderRadius: sizes.radius,
                overflow: 'hidden',
                flexDirection: 'row',
              }}>
              <Image
                style={{
                  borderRadius: sizes.radius,
                  width: 160,
                  height: CardHeight - 60,
                  resizeMode: 'cover',
                }}
                source={props.image}
              />

              <View style={{marginTop: spacing.l}}>
                <View style={{marginLeft: spacing.l, marginBottom: spacing.s}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: '#FA4A0C'}}>
                    {props.title}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{marginLeft: spacing.l}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 14, color: '#8b8989'}}>
                    {props.price}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 130}}>
                  <AddItem />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      ); })
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

ProductItem

```
import React from 'react';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';

const ProductItem = ({list}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {list.length > 0 &&
        list.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <ProductCard
              id={item._id}
              image={item.image}
              title={item.title}
              price={item.price}
              item={item}
              key={index}
            />
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductItem;
```

[console.log(product)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Qnp.jpg)

Comment: Did you try like this : `const data = await instance.get('/api/products')` ? and `setProduct(data.data)` since it's in the data property with the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost will not work with your react native app try to use ngrok to change the url

Comment: I tried using the database link or changing it to the computer's ip but it still doesn't work

Comment: https://articles.wesionary.team/localhost-to-react-native-expo-projects-f0e4ce7d624f this article will help you